# Getting access violation because of ID3D11Buffer

Tags: directx, directx11, vertex-arrays

I try to create a simple class store my model variables vertex array and vertexbuffer. So I create an array of myclass to create and manage object dynamically. But when

```
 hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &pieces[counter].g_pVertexBuffer);
```

this line run I get the error "Access violation reading location". I try to many things but I never success. If I don't use class and array I don't get this error. Porgram runs without error.

MyClass:

```
class Piece
{
public:
  double positionX, positionZ,
    red, green,blue;
  bool renderable;
  int type, color, vertexCount;
  XMMATRIX g_WorldPieces;
  ID3D11Buffer* g_pVertexBuffer;
  SimpleVertex* vertices;
  Piece();
  void create(int, int, double, double);
};
Piece::Piece()
{
   g_pVertexBuffer = NULL;
}
 void Piece::create(int t, int c, double pX, double pZ)
{
   g_pVertexBuffer = NULL;
   renderable = true;
   type = t;
   color = c;
   red=green=blue=0.0f;
   if(color == 1)
     red=green=blue=1.0f;
   positionX = pX;
   positionZ = pZ;
   vertexCount = 0;
}

  Piece *pieces;//Global variable which define after defining "ID3D11Device*                       g_pd3dDevice = NULL"
```

and using objects of myclass:

```
for(int x=0;x<4;x++)
{
if(x==2)
{
    c=0;
    positionZ = 12.5;
}

for(int y=0;y<8;y++)
{
    pieces[counter].create(typeArray[x][y],c,positionX,positionZ);
    positionX += 5;
    switch(pieces[counter].type)
    {
         //Switching object txt. All cases and breaks are fine. 
    }
    fin >> pieces[counter].vertexCount;
    pieces[counter].vertices = new SimpleVertex[vertexCount];
    for(int i=0; i<vertexCountpiyon; i++)
    {
        fin >> pieces[counter].vertices[i].Pos.x >> pieces[counter].vertices[i].Pos.y >> pieces[counter].vertices[i].Pos.z;
        fin >> pieces[counter].vertices[i].Tex.x >> pieces[counter].vertices[i].Tex.y;
        fin >> pieces[counter].vertices[i].Normal.x >> pieces[counter].vertices[i].Normal.y >> pieces[counter].vertices[i].Normal.z;
    }   
    fin.close();
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( SimpleVertex ) *pieces[counter].vertexCount;
    ZeroMemory( &InitData, sizeof(InitData) );
    InitData.pSysMem = pieces[counter].vertices;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &pieces[counter].g_pVertexBuffer);//THIS LINE IS MY PROBLEM!
    if( FAILED( hr ) )     return hr;
    counter++;
}
positionX = -17.5;
positionZ += 5;
}
```

When I get access violation counter is 0.

Source code of my project: http://1drv.ms/1nKdoUf

Comment: An access violation typically means one of the pointers you are passing in is invalid.  Double-check that the `pieces` array has enough elements, and ensure all the pointers are pointing somewhere valid, including `g_pd3dDevice`.

Comment: I can't see any reason for error. If you have directx 11 and visual studio 12, you can download all project and try to find reason.

Comment: You have an opportunity to learn to troubleshoot and solve your own problems, why would you want someone to fix it for you? You will be  worse off than you were before, because then you wouldn't know how to prevent the problem from happening again.

Comment: Step one: learn good codeformatting practices. Makes it easier for everyone (including you) to read. :)

Comment: This site is not about debugging your project for you.

Comment: If I can see any error I don't need t ask it. About codeformatting you are right. And my purpose is not debugging my project. I want only help when I don't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that you are trying to create a vertex buffer with invalid initial data because you have actually no vertices in your array.

```
for(int i=0; i<vertexCountpiyon; i++)
```

If you inspect this loop (line 748 in your code) then you see that it is not entered by the program because *vertexCountpiyon* variable is zero. So your vertex array is not filled and you are trying to read from it that's why you get an access violation error.
(Please note that debugging your code questions is usually not warmly welcome on this site, this time you got lucky I guess :) )